# Split string with commas but ignore the ones within double quotes

Tags: javascript, csv, salesforce-lightning

Input var str='john,doe,"1,234.56",0.00,true'

I tried using following regex

```
var arr = str.match(/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);
```

but getting error of unterminated string .

A non-regex solution to achieve the following output

Desired output :

john,doe,1,234.56,0.00,true

```js
var str='john,doe,"1,234.56",0.00,true'
var arr = str.match(/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g);
console.log(arr.join("."))
```

Comment: desired output does not match the subject.

Comment: I would solve that with two level regex, first extract all strings that are in an double quotes and than split them depending on commas (by ignoring those that were  in double quotes)

Comment: please share how

Comment: @mplungjan I think that's the problem.  He's using that solution but it isn't working as he expects

Comment: @user120242 as you can see in the snippet I just made, it works fine

Comment: @mplungjan he wants it to strip the quotes for him.  although honestly don't know why he doesn't just trim them off.  oh, he's asking about unterminated string.  must be a salesforce thing with quotes

Comment: Where does it say that? That is not possible. "1,234.56" is a string

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not the OP, but the OP's desired output does not include the quotes around ,1,234.56,0.00,  so he wants  "1,234.56,0.00" not "\"1,234.56,0.00\"".  None of those examples strip the quotes for you.  Need another dupe link for stripping quotes.

Comment: The escaped quotes are the console log - to strip quotes do a join and a simple replace but then you have a string again with commas

Comment: @mplungjan you mean .map and trim or slice right? right now it gives `"\"1234\""` not `"1234"` because the regex matches on `".*?"`.  what he wants is `(?<").*?(?=")` to exclude quotes, or `"(.*?)"` and extracting the third match group (must use matchAll).  or `.map(x=>x[0]==='"'&&x[x.length-1]==='"'?x.slice(1,-1):x)`.  the last solution being trivial enough that he should have been able to find a (separate) dupe for it without much issue

Comment: @mplungjan `'john,doe,"1,234.56",0.00,true'.match(/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g)[2] !== "1,234.56"` but `'john,doe,"1,234.56",0.00,true'.match(/(".*?"|[^",\s]+)(?=\s*,|\s*$)/g)[2] === '"\"1,234.56\""`

Answer (score 0):

you can use `negative looakahead` and `negative lookbehind`

```js
var str='john,doe,"1,234.56",0.00,true';
var out = str.match(/(?<!\")([\w\.]+)(?!")(?:,|$)/g)
console.log(out)
```

Comment: When are Safari and Firefox going to support lookbehinds ☹